# VBA, Search in Subfolders

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am looking in the Folder for specific file in .docx and want to open it. I put the Name of X into Inputbox, go to Sheet Y, look on the next right cell of X and open this as Word (next cell right is an file in word I want to open). It is working, but the Problem is that the target Word Doc may be in multiples subfolders. Is there any quick way to search in These subfolder?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim AppWD As Object
    Dim SearchX As String
    Dim SearchArea As Range
    Dim Y As String
    Dim sPath As String

    sPath = "C:\Users\VS\Desktop\test"

    SearchRule = InputBox("X")
    Set SearchArea = Sheets("Look").Range("A:A").Find(what:=SearchX, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole)

    ActiveWindow.Visible = True
    Target = SearchArea.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Set AppWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    AppWD.Visible = True
    AppWD.documents.Open (sPath & "\" & Target & "." & "docx")

    ErrorHandling: Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

My take on searching throught subfolders

```
Sub searchSub()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject, fFile As File, fFolder As Folder
    Dim fSubFolder As Folder, fPath As String, FileToSearch As String

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    FileToSearch = "SomeDocument.docx"
    fPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Set fFolder = fso.GetFolder(fPath)

    For Each fFolder In fFolder.SubFolders
            Set fSubFolder = fso.GetFolder(fFolder.Path)

            For Each fFile In fSubFolder.Files
                If fFile.Name = FileToSearch Then
                    'do something with file
                End If
            Next fFile
    Next fFolder
End Sub
```